# Does the dialog style DS_FIXEDSYS still make sense today?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2022

I wonder if the `DS_FIXEDSYS` dialog style still makes sense today.

As far as I understood after reading [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050207-00/?p=36513) is doesn't, but the Visual Studio 2022 resource editor still puts this style seemingly randomly in .rc files.

Example:

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 170, 62
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Fake App"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
    LTEXT           "Fake App, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2023",IDC_STATIC,42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
END

IDD_FAKE_APP_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,207,179,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14
    CTEXT           "TODO: Place dialog controls here.",IDC_STATIC,13,48,300,8
END
```

Can anyone confirm that `DS_FIXEDSYS` does definitely not make sense anymore today (2023)?

Comment: It is the "Use System Font" property in the dialog editor, defaults to True.  Relentless attention to backward compatibility, dialog by themselves can easily produce the "ux designed in 1990" look-and-feel.   I suppose the monospace font can still be handy to make aligned columns, give or take.

Comment: As [Why does DS_SHELLFONT = DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_SETFONT?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050207-00/?p=36513) explains, when that flag appears along with `DS_SETFONT`, it doesn't mean `DS_FIXEDSYS`, it means `DS_SHELLFONT`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to explain based on all the information.

When `WINVER >= 0x0400` and `DS_FIXEDSYS` is used alone, it does as [Dialog Box Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dialog-box-styles) says:

> Causes the dialog box to use the SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT instead of the
> default SYSTEM_FONT. This is a monospace font compatible with the
> System font in 16-bit versions of Windows earlier than 3.0.

When `DS_FIXEDSYS` is used with `DS_SETFONT`, that means `DS_SHELLFONT`, using the system font, in `WINVER >= 0x0400` and `DS_SETFONT` in `WINVER < 0x0400`.